# Send Token and page in laravel pagination and firebase-jwt-token

Tags: laravel, jwt

Hai I tried to send page on api request but it seems the token is not readable. 
[image]

it says error while decoding token. but if im not put "?page=1" it works well

[image]

when i put token in the header the token not readable too

[image]

im using **jwt-firebase** plugin BTW

*sorry for my bad english

Comment: convert your GET request to POST and send two different params as key-value one for token and other for page

Comment: Also if you are using GET then for the second onward param you have to use &page=1 not ?page=1 as I can see in your screenshot

Comment: dear Sagar, i finnaly figure it out . im using getbearerToken() instead to get token. and it solved a problem

Answer (score 0):

somehow i figure it out .

i put token in the authorization Bearer and in the controller i catch it with request->getbearerToken(). thanks